# Python repeat while user enters negative number

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am new to python but am struggling to figure out how to take user input and keep asking until the user enters a positive number. The problem I have is that my script does not repeat even when I enter negative numbers.

```
padding = -1    
while (padding < 0):
    padding = raw_input('Enter crop padding:')
```

How can I make it repeat until padding is positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. What happens is that `raw_input()` returns a string, so you have to convert it to `int`:

```
padding = -1    
while (padding < 0):
    padding = int(raw_input('Enter crop padding:'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` return a string, so you need to convert it to integer to compare with 0.

```
padding = -1    
while (padding < 0):
    padding = int(raw_input('Enter crop padding:'))
```